# VueJs: API call in mounted very slow

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my Vue js project i have problem with API data, the page loads fast but data from API takes more than 5 sec to load. However, my Api response is very fast in console.
in below code i implemented api in other file called API services and i put a class that contains all my APIs called `BuildingService`, so i called API on mounted and it loads slow
can any one help me in this?

```js
<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import BuildingsService from "@/services/ApiService"

  Vue.use(VueClipboard)
  export default {
    data(){
      return{
buildings:[],

      }
    },
    name: 'icons',
    components: {
      BaseHeader
    },
  
    mounted:function(){
          BuildingsService.getBuildings().then((response) => {
      this.buildings = response.data.response;
      console.log(response.data.response,"dd");

    });
    }

   
   
          
      
  };
</script>
```

```html
 
              <b-col lg="3" md="6"  v-for="(building, index) in buildings"
              :key="index" >
>{{building.building_number}}
   
              </b-col>
```

Comment: My wild guess is that you're returning a lot of data and that you're trying to render all of it. In other words, it's irrelevant that the data is coming from the API request. Even if you had it in your component, it would still take long to render all that data. By *"render"* I mean the time the browser takes to create DOM elements corresponding to all the data being displayed on your page. Also note that your issue is not reproducible using the code you have shared. Without being able to repro, nobody can test potential solutions, so your question is not answerable, therefore *"off-topic"*.

Comment: If my assumption is correct, using ***a)*** some form of pagination or ***b)*** a virtual scroller, will fix the problem. The basic principle behind these solutions is: the browser window has a limited amount of screen real estate. You should only build enough DOM elements to fill that real estate and only create more when the user changes page (solution ***a)***) or scrolls (solution ***b)***). Note the virtual scroller solution is only an option when all the scrolled children have the same height. If that's not the case, pagination would be the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

use created instead of mounted:

```
created() {
      BuildingsService.getBuildings().then((response) => {
      this.buildings = response.data.response;
      console.log(response.data.response,"dd");
    });
}
```

for reference: [enter link description here](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html)